# Yii2: Class 'kartik\file\FileInput' not found, but I have it in my vendor. What could be wrong?

Tags: php, yii2

I installed this widget through the composer like this

```
    php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput "dev-master"
```

In my composer.json I have `"kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "dev-master"`
and it even added to my vendor, but when I am going to use it, I get an error `Class 'kartik\file\FileInput' not found`.

I tried to use that widget in my view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'upload-files',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'upload-form',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ]
]);
echo $form->field($model, 'attachment')->widget(\kartik\file\FileInput::class, [
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'image/*',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' =>  ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'tiff'],
        'showUpload' => false,
        'showRemove' => false,
        'dropZoneEnabled' => true,
    ]
]);
?>
```

What could be wrong and how I can fix that problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the one from the repository [yii2-widget-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput) and run this command:

php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput "@dev"